# how to make a discord bot have a conversation with you

Tags: python, discord

How do I make a bot that respond to user input and base of that user input it will respond again?

example -

```
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f"{username}: {user_message} ({channel})")
    
    if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
        x = await message.channel.send(f'hello {username}')
    if x == "how are you?":
        await message.channel.send(f"i am fine how are you?")
```

Comment: I am not an expert with `discord` library. However, I think the last if-statement should be comparing `user_message.lower()` and not `x`.

Comment: Sorry for posting another comment but I can not edit my previous comment anymore. Please use `elif` instead of the second if-statement.

Comment: I tried both, and i meant to write elif but i made a typo